# Find index position of character within string without accessing the string variable again, in Java

Tags: java, sql, string, resultset

This is because the string is got from a ResultSet which returns no value if the string is accessed again.

My position is like this.

```
ResultSet rst  = pst.executeQuery(); //pst is a preparedstatement
value = Integer.parseInt(rst.getString(1).trim().substring(0,<need to get position of '.' here>)
```

If I give rst.getString(1) again, it gives me an exception as no data found.

I have a workaround to store the string in a temporary variable and access it.

I needed to know if there was something like 'this' object to access the current string within a function of that string.

Thanks

Comment: I believe your best bet is storing it in a temporary variable. I don't think you will loose much if any performance and I don't see a way to do it otherwise.

Comment: rst.getString should not throw an execption here. Just accessing the string doesn't move the resultset to the next row.

Comment: but it does, 'java.sql.SQLException: No data found' was returned, for `code`Integer.parseInt(rst.getString(1).substring(0,rst.getString(1).indexOf(".")))`code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save rst.getString(1) to new string variable

String st=rst.getString(1);

or use somthing like this

rst.getString(1).split("\.")[0].trim()

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, that works great with a slight modification, rst.getString(1).split("\\.")[0].trim()

Answer (score 3):

What speaks against storing the string in a temporary variable?

Comment: basically since there were variables lying around everywhere in the code, just wanted to know if anyone knew a better method...